# How to avoid a memory leak with __block and completion blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

I have a situation where an object needs to be initialized with a completion block which accesses the said object. To make such access possible, the object is defined as __block. The problem is this object never becomes deallocated. Take a look at the following example.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    __block MyViewController* myViewController = [[MyViewController] alloc] initWithCompletion:^{
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [myViewController.navigationController 
                pushViewController:[[GoodViewController alloc] init]
                animated:YES
            ];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            [myViewController.navigationController 
                pushViewController:[[BadViewController alloc] init]
                animated:YES
            ];
        }
    }];
}
```

All is well except myViewController's dealloc is never called when it is popped from the navigation stack. When I remove __block, dealloc will eventually be called, but doing so prevents me from accessing myViewController inside its completion block. How would I access an object inside its own completion block without a memory leak?

Comment: An init method cannot be asynchronous. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @CrimsonChris: A completion block is not necessarily called asynchronously.

Comment: @MartinR In my experience it is. Perhaps the block should be renamed? If the block is designed to be used for navigation after some action has been performed it should probably be called `initWithNavigationBlock:`.

Comment: As hinted at below, the __block won't be required if you break the process up into two steps.  allocate, init, assign in one statement.  Then assign the completion block as a separate statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view controller is retaining the block, and the block is retaining the `myViewController`, creating a retain cycle.

Think of it like this...  The view controller puts a leash around the block to keep it from deallocating until the view controller is done.  The block puts a leash around the view controller to keep it from deallocating until the block is done.

Neither will release the reference to the other until the other first release its reference... thus a retain cycle.

There are a number of ways to avoid retain cycles, depending on how you use the block.

In your case, I would have the completion block pass back the view controller to which the block is attached.  This will easily avoid the need to retain the object itself.

```
MyViewController* myViewController = [[MyViewController] alloc]
    initWithCompletion:^(MyViewController *viewController) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [viewController.navigationController 
            pushViewController:[[GoodViewController alloc] init]
                      animated:YES
        ];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        [viewController.navigationController 
            pushViewController:[[BadViewController alloc] init]
                      animated:YES
        ];
    }
}];
```

In your MyViewController class, you simply call the block with...

```
if (_completionBlock) _completionBlock(self);
```

When you design an interface, try to make it as easy to use as possible, without imposing undue restrictions on the user.  In this case, by passing the controller back to the block as an argument, you let the user write code that does not have to worry about the retain cycle created between the controller and the block.

Comment: May I ask how the block retains the view controller? Does `__block` implicitly call `[myViewController retain]`?

Comment: Your block uses several variables not declared as parameters to the block: `indexPath` and `myViewController`.  The block needs to make sure these variables are still around when the block executes.  Thus, it "captures" those variables to make sure they are still alive.  Any POD is copied.  However, if the variable is a pointer-to-a-retainable-object, that object is sent a retain, to make sure it survives.  When the block deallocates, it will send a release to all those objects that it retained.  The block and VC hold references to each other: a retain cycle.  Neither will ever deallocate.

Comment: The `__block` keyword does not do the retain.  It just does a little magic so that the captured variable is a "reference" to a shared variable and not a copy.  The reason the compiler was forcing you to use `__block` was because `myViewController` had not yet been assigned when it was captured by the block.  Thus, you were capturing an uninitialized variable... it is not assigned a value until the `initWithCompletion` returns... but the block is created beforehand... so making it `__block` allowed the block to reference the variable even though it's value was not set until later.

Comment: this changes the API of the class, which the user may not be at liberty to do

Comment: @newacct Of course it does.  That was part of the point.  The current API contributes to the ease with which the user can create this retain cycle, so changing the API would certainly help.  At worst, the addition of a more appropriate `init` method in a category on a third-party class would accomplish the same thing.  So, I'd be interested to know why you think the user would not be at liberty to change the API (an addition to the existing API is a change).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of __block use __weak but set your block after initialising and within the block access through weak reference.

```
    MyViewController* myViewController = [[MyViewController] alloc] init];
    __weak typeof(myViewController) weakVC = myViewController;
    myViewController.completion = ^{
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [weakVC 
                pushViewController:[[GoodViewController alloc] init]
                animated:YES
            ];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            [weakVC 
                pushViewController:[[BadViewController alloc] init]
                animated:YES
            ];
        }
    };
```

You really have to think about what's going on with ARC with these kind of situations to ensure everything releases as expected !

Comment: this changes the API of the class, which the user may not be at liberty to do

Answer (score 0):

`init` methods shouldn't be asynchronous. Perhaps this is the approach you seek.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController] alloc] init];
    __weak MyViewController weakMyViewController = myViewController;
    myViewController.navigationBlock = ^{
        UIViewController *viewControllerToPush;
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            viewControllerToPush = [[GoodViewController alloc] init];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            viewControllerToPush = [[BadViewController alloc] init];
        }
        [weakMyViewController.navigationController
         pushViewController:viewControllerToPush
         animated:YES
         ];
    };
    //myViewController* goes out of scope here... You probably should keep a reference to it somehow
}
```

Comment: My `init` is synchronous. The completion block is called after the user performs some action.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on your question, you should consider renaming your completion block to something more specific. For instance, if you are running the block when the user clicks a "next" button, you could name the block 'onNextButtonPressedBlock'.

Comment: The problem is that "completion" is a loaded word in iOS. When you say "do something" with completion, it's implied that the completion will run when the "do something" is finished.

Comment: this changes the API of the class, which the user may not be at liberty to do

Answer (score 0):

There is a retain cycle, because the view controller probably retains the completion block (we don't see the code, so we can't be sure; but most likely it does), and the block retains the view controller because the block captures the variable `myViewController`.

To do this in ARC without a retain cycle, you need the block to capture a weak reference to the view controller. However, you must also have at least one strong reference to the view controller, or else it would be immediately eligible to be deallocated. Therefore, you need two variables, one weak and captured by the block (and `__block` because its value will be set after the block is created, but needs to be used by the block), and one strong:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    MyViewController* myViewController;
    __block __weak MyViewController* myViewControllerWeak;
    myViewControllerWeak = myViewController = [[MyViewController] alloc] initWithCompletion:^{
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [myViewControllerWeak.navigationController 
                pushViewController:[[GoodViewController alloc] init]
                animated:YES
            ];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            [myViewControllerWeak.navigationController 
                pushViewController:[[BadViewController alloc] init]
                animated:YES
            ];
        }
    }];
}
```

This fixes the problem without changing the API of the class.

Comment: The OP never claimed to be using a class that could not be changed. After all, the OP called it `MyViewController`. The "best" solution would be to expose the block outside of the init method. However, if that is not possible, your solution is the only "correct" one.